# Authentication options for staging sites

Tags: active-directory, authentication, windows, azure

We're currently authenticating our clients who wants to view their staging environments using windows authentication. That means we have to create their accounts in our local AD and assign them to particular roles.

What are the other's doing? How about Azure AD? Is it possible to achieve the similar behaviour that we have now? We just think that our clients should not be in our on premise AD but somewhere like Azure AD.

Of course, we want to avoid code changes to accomodate such authentication.

Your insights will be valuable.

Edit:

Yes, I'm referring to websites / web applications.

Our case is, we're using different kinds of Content Management Systems and custom web applications, which 99% (in our case) of the time uses Forms Authentication. However, this Forms authentication is used at the application level. We want something that would add a layer of authentication that will give access to the user before the application even gets the request. This layer of authentication should then authorize them to view and use the staging website/ web app.

We don't want this new layer of authentication to interfere with the forms authentication. This is simply to make these staging sites viewable by the owner (client/customer). We've thought of IP filtering per site but the problem is we sometimes have clients who are using mobile phones to check their websites while their out and about in which IP addresses are dynamic.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `We're currently authenticating our clients who wants to view their staging environments using windows authentication` - That doesn't mean anything to anyone but you. How about some details? I'm assuming you're referring to web sites/web applications?

Comment: I added more info. Let me know if you still need more.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do anything without changing code. Azure AD does not allow Windows Authentication and stuff like that from IIS servers because you cannot join them to the "Windows Azure Domain". You would need to go over OAuth / ADFS or stuff like that. (requiring code changes)

Comment: Is your comment still true with my above edit? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I do believe it's still true, but I'm not an expert in WAAD or Azure in general

Comment: You could of course just join the staging webserver(s) to their own AD Domain... and separate them